# Rails API with subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, subdomain

I tried this API routes setting in my app's routes.rb

```
constraints :subdomain => "api" do
    namespace :api, path: nil, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
      namespace :v1, path: nil do
        resources :articles, only: :index
        resources :tags, only: :index
      end
    end
  end
```

it's seems OK(rake routes)

```
api_v1_articles GET    /articles(.:format)   api/v1/articles#index {:subdomain=>"api", :format=>"json"}
api_v1_tags GET    /tags(.:format)   api/v1/tags#index {:subdomain=>"api", :format=>"json"}
```

but no matter in development or production, i sent request to

```
http://api.ip:3000/articles
http://api.ip:3000/tags
```

both render my root page html, if I don't use subdomain, it work fine.

and if I use

```
http://api.ip:3000
```

it can access my root just like use http://ip:3000.

what's the problem with this? did I miss something or setting?

---

error msg:

```
Started GET "/articles" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-16 10:10:42 +0800
Processing by ApplicationController#not_found as */*
  Parameters: {"unmatched_route"=>"articles"}
```

my setting:

```
class Api::V1::ArticlesController < Api::V1::ApplicationController
```

Comment: In development you need to setup your internal OS routing so that you can point a domain like `api.myapp.dev` to `127.0.0.1`. How to achieve that depends on what OS you are using.

Comment: I already tried to edit /etc/hosts in mac.

Comment: Maybe try debugging by checking `logger.debug( request.subdomains.inspect )` it should give you `[ "api" ]`. If it is empty that means that the request is being forwarded even before it hits Rack. Thus the error is not in your routes (which look correct).

Comment: https://reinteractive.net/posts/199-developing-and-testing-rails-applications-with-subdomains